# Pre hoc ANOVA tests

Tags: anova

When conducting tests for normality and variance ahead of an Anova should you perform one set of tests using all the response data or a series of tests, grouping the response data according to the main factors.

Answer (score 1):

ANOVA is fairly robust to non-normality as long as the data appear to be symmetric and unimodal (within groups).

You honestly don't need to worry about testing for normality.

If the data don't appear to be normal, or roughly normal, then do a different test, like Kruskal-Wallis (more than two groups) or Mann-Whitney U test.

Comment: I'll ask again else where